# Erlang ++ operator. Syntactic sugar, or separate operation?

Tags: erlang

Is Erlang's `++` operator simply syntactic sugar for `lists:concat` or is it a different operation altogether? I've tried searching this, but it's impossible to Google for "++" and get anything useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how the `lists:concat/1` is implemented in the stdlib/lists module:

```
concat(List) ->
    flatmap(fun thing_to_list/1, List).
```

Where:

```
flatmap(F, [Hd|Tail]) ->
    F(Hd) ++ flatmap(F, Tail);
flatmap(F, []) when is_function(F, 1) -> [].
```

and:

```
thing_to_list(X) when is_integer(X) -> integer_to_list(X);
thing_to_list(X) when is_float(X)   -> float_to_list(X);
thing_to_list(X) when is_atom(X)    -> atom_to_list(X);
thing_to_list(X) when is_list(X)    -> X.   %Assumed to be a string
```

So, `lists:concat/1` actually uses the '++' operator.

Comment: Yea reading the source code is great, but that unfortunately involves *reading the source code* ;-)

Answer (score 8):

`X ++ Y` is in fact syntactic sugar for `lists:append(X, Y)`.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#append-2

The function lists:concat/2 is a different beast. The documentation describes it as follows: "Concatenates the text representation of the elements of Things. The elements of Things can be atoms, integers, floats or strings."

Answer (score 4):

One important use of `++` has not been mentioned yet: In pattern matching. For example:

```
handle_url(URL = "http://" ++ _) -> 
    http_handler(URL);
handle_url(URL = "ftp://" ++ _) ->
    ftp_handler(URL).
```

Comment: @Travis: No it's not, it is equivalent to [$h,$t,$t,$p,$:,$/,$/|_]

Answer (score 3):

It's an entirely different operation. ++ is ordinary list appending. lists:concat takes a single argument (which must be a list), stringifies its elements, and concatenates the strings.

++ : http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html

lists:concat : http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html

Answer (score 1):

Most list functions actually uses the '++' operator:
for example the list:append/2:

The source code defines it as follows:

```
-spec append(List1, List2) -> List3 when
      List1 :: [T],
      List2 :: [T],
      List3 :: [T],
      T :: term().

append(L1, L2) -> L1 ++ L2.
```