# lists:append/2 versus erlang:'++' /2, appending to end of list Versus appending to its Head

Tags: list, erlang, append

Of the two given pairs of comparisons, Which one (of each pair) is more expensive to System Resources in Erlang:

**Qn1:** `lists:append(L1,L2)` versus `erlang:'++'(L1,L2)`
**Qn2** Writing to the head of a list with say: `[NewHead|List]` versus writing to the end of the list with: `List ++ [NewValue]`

I have asked this because there is an intensive part of my program which will be reading and writing into lists. I need to decide wether i will be writing to the lists' heads or writing to their ends, or vice versa.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1: They are the same function. 'append' is an alias for '++' (or vice versa). See also [Erlang ++ operator. Syntactic sugar, or separate operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339176/erlang-operator-syntactic-sugar-or-separate-operation)

2: Don't build a list incrementally by appending. Appending once is OK, but appending in a loop will give you quadratic behaviour. I.e., AddedStuff ++ Accumulator is OK (even in a loop), because you're growing "to the left", but Accumulator ++ AddedStuff in a loop (growing to the right) is really bad. It's much better to grow to the left and then reverse or sort afterwards if the order is important.